# passing json data from angularjs to WCF is throws 400 bad request error

Tags: c#, angularjs, json, wcf

Calling this function on a button click
**angular function**

```
$scope.CreateNewTopic = function () {
          var userdata = {
        TopicName:$scope.topicname,
        TopicDescription: $scope.topicdescription,
        OriginalPosterID: $scope.userid,
        CategoryID: $scope.selectedcategory
    };
        DataService.InsertTopicObject(userdata)
```

The service method is as below

```
InsertTopicObject: function (topic) {
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: connectionurl + 'InsertNewTopic',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8' },

                data:  topic 
            })
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                // successcallback(data); 
                console.log(data);
            })
            .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $log.warn(data, status, headers, config);
            })
        }
```

WCF

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/InsertNewTopic", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
        int InsertNewTopic(InsertNewTopic InsertTopicObject);

public int InsertNewTopic(InsertNewTopic InsertTopicObject) {

            return SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(SqlConnectionString.GetConnection(), CommandType.StoredProcedure, Constants.SP_Name.ToString(), new SqlParameter("TopicName", InsertTopicObject.TopicName), new SqlParameter("TopicDescription", InsertTopicObject.TopicDescription), new SqlParameter("OriginalPosterID", InsertTopicObject.OriginalPosterID), new SqlParameter("CategoryID", InsertTopicObject.CategoryID));

        }
```

The following error I get.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44rur.png)

Comment: Api expects content type Json. Try to remove `Content-Type` header. (Or even remove this line at all `headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8' },`)

Comment: Thanks Aleksey. I tried the same and it is not working getting same error. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You should double check the data you're sending. When `RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped` specified, the expected body format is: `{"parameterName":parameterValue}`.
So you have two options here:

**1** - You can change `BodyStyle` to `WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare`
**2** - Another option is to send your data "wrapped":

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: connectionurl + 'InsertNewTopic',
    data:  {
        'InsertTopicObject' : topic
    }
})
```

Comment: Aleksey Please check the below error in my console    

`Object {method: "POST", transformRequest: Array[1], transformResponse: Array[1], url: "http://localhost:8020/DFServices.svc/InsertNewTopic", data: Object…}
data:Object
InsertTopicObject:Object
CategoryID:3
OriginalPosterID:"11"
TopicDescription:"<pre><!--block-->sample sample<br>sample description</pre>"
TopicName:"Sample data"`
Please provide me a solution for the above data along with that for your information

Comment: can you provide me one solution please.